# Can't create a Compute Engine instance template that assigns ephemeral external IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am running the following command (mostly copied from the GCP console) to create an instance template with a custom boot disk:

```bash
gcloud --project=$PROJECT \
  compute instance-templates create indesign-server-template-$TIMESTAMP \
  --machine-type=$MACHINE_TYPE \
  --network-interface=network=default,network-tier=PREMIUM \
  --no-restart-on-failure --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --provisioning-model=STANDARD \
  --service-account=$SVC_ACCOUNT \
  --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append \
  --tags=http-server,https-server \
  --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=indesign-server-template-$TIMESTAMP,image=projects/$PROJECT/global/images/indesign-server-image-$TIMESTAMP,mode=rw,size=100,type=pd-balanced \
  --reservation-affinity=any
```

When I view the template in the console, here's what I see under "Network Interfaces":
[image: actual result]

But here's what I want to see (from a template I created by point-and-click):
[image: expexted-result]

From reading the `gcloud` docs I am passing the right options to `--network-interface`, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try adding an `address` flag and leave the string empty. So it should look like this

```
--network-interface=network=default,network-tier=PREMIUM,address=''
```

Comment: Document link for this setting: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create#--network-interface